# js works or doesn't on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

I need JS `onclick` event but it works very strange for me and I can't figure out why. There're three examples below and I don't understand why the first one doesn't.

/ First

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("button#clear-id").click(function(){      // this one doesn't work
    alert('Howdy');
});
...
```

/  Second

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("body").click(function(){      // this one works
    alert('Howdy');
});
...
```

/ Third

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(document).on('click', '#clear-id', function () {    // this one works
  alert("Hello!");
});
...
```

/ HTML of the button looks like

```
<button type="button" class="close" id="clear-id" aria-label="Close" value="';   the_ID(); echo'">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)

Comment: [Can't reproduce.](http://jsfiddle.net/591ku2z8/)

Comment: I can see some similarities but I think my question is different. Why $("#clear-id").click(function(){     doesn't work ? The selector works but the function doesn't.

Comment: Ivar I already tested this on jsfiddle even for multiple buttons to get their values but on my local.wp it wants $(document) to work

Answer (score -1):

Evidently the selector in the first one is wrong, use only $('#clear-id') instead, because I'm not sure but I think you can't combine tag with id in the same selector.

Comment: the selector works but the function doesn't... I tried to use only $('#clear-id') and still nothing

Comment: Combining a tag with an id/class is perfectly valid.